# Invalid implicit conversion from uint256[10] memory to uint256[] memory requested

Tags: solidity, dynamic-arrays

So apparently we can not use dynamic arrays while using memory data location. But the following code gives me error:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

contract A {
    uint256[] public numbers;
    
    constructor(uint256[] memory _numbers) {
        for(uint256 i=0; i<_numbers.length; i++) {
            numbers.push(_numbers[i]);
        }
    }

    function get() public view returns (uint256[] memory) {
        return numbers;
    }
}

contract Manager {
    function makeA() public returns(uint256) {
        uint256[10] memory numbers;
        // push is not supported for memory data location of array
        numbers[0] = 10;

        A a = new A(numbers); //Error: Invalid implicit conversion from uint256[10] memory to uint256[] memory requested

        return a.numbers(0);
    }
}
```

I solved it using this syntax of declaring static array:

```
uint256[] memory numbers = new uint256[](5);
```

Although it solved the issue but I am still confused behind the concept of why the later works? My assumption is that solidity differs the type between uint256[] and uint256[10]. Correct me if I am wrong, also an explanation of this behavior will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The error says cannot convert static array to dynamic array implicitly.

In Java, whenever you pass Integer wrapper to int or int to Integer, you don't have to explicitly convert it. the compiler does it for you. In the same way, some conversion happens at the compiler level known as implicit conventions.

In EVM, when you passed numbers[10] that says that you are declaring a static type array. In the constructor, you are pushing it into a dynamic array. compiler by default cannot convert it into unit[10] to unit[]. this is what the error says.

when you declare that with help of a [new](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/solidity/solidity_arrays.htm) keyword it is one way to declare a dynamic array. so, the dynamic array is passed and values will be inserted into the dynamic array. so, no conversion is required.

if you feel, the answer needs to be updated please update it.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is as follows:

Firstly, a static array will have its memory slots allocated when defined.

Yet dynamic arrays will require a new allocation to be issued every time you push a new element into it.

This might not seem like a big thing in a normal OOP language, but Solidity requires gas per instruction, and that's where that difference can't be ignored.